# If $f(x)$ is a polynomial, is it true that $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}\frac{1}{f(x)}$ both exist?

Tags: analysis

If $y=f(x)$ is a polynomial, then $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac1{f(x)}$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac1{f(x)}$ both exist.

I need explain that why it's true or false.

Comment: Welcome to mathematics stackexchange. What have you tried? What is your guess of the answer, and why?

Comment: There is an edge case that may cause problems...

Comment: @BrianMoehring only one edge case, no?

Comment: @BrianMoehring It's hard for me to visualize any edge case other than $f(x) = 0$.  Beyond that, if $f$ is of degree $n$, any of the roots of $f$ must be **finite**.  In fact, the case of $f(x) = k$, where $k \neq 0$ should probably be considered separately from $f$ being a polynomial of degree greater than $0$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Of course!  I was also thinking of the cases where the proof would deviate, but those aren't a problem for the statement.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, assume that $f(x)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$.  That is, it has form $x^n + a_{(n_1)}x^{(n-1)} + \cdots + a_1x^1 + a_0.$

Attack the problem with intuition.  Suppose (for example) that $n$ is odd.  Can you prove (for example) that the $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty.$

Can you **then**, using a similar approach, prove that the $\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0.$

What about the supposition that each of the coefficients 
$\{a_{(n-1)}, \cdots, a_0\}$ is an element of $[-M,M]$, for some (large) **fixed** positive real $M$?